# What taxes or fees should employer pay to keep an employee's work permit and residence safe in Sweden?

Tags: taxes, employment, sweden

I moved to Sweden few month ago due to an employment agreement with some Swedish company.
I moved here with my wife, so we both have the personal number and Swedish id card.
Also, I have work permit card that is attached to the employer.

A few weeks ago I read the information about some deportation cases.

https://www.thelocal.se/20171213/ruling-from-swedens-migration-court-of-appeal-could-stop-deportations-of-foreign-workers-over-technicalities

https://www.thelocal.se/20170220/spotify-slams-ridiculous-deportation-threat-faced-by-staff-in-sweden

Due to this information, I'd like to know:

1. How can I check these "minor" mistakes with my employment to avoid these technicalities and being forced to leave Sweden?
2. Is there is, in Sweden, some agency like Skatteverket or Migrationsverket that can provide full information about occupational pension insurance payments and others by an employer?
3. Could anyone tell me what fees or taxes should exactly employer pay?

Answer (score 1):

1. Talk to the management about your concerns, if they're unwilling to help talk directly to the union.
2. The issue at hand is adhering to the collective bargaining agreements ("kollektivavtal"). In order to prevent wage dumping ("lönedumpning"), immigrants on work visas must have wages and benefits at least at the minimum level specified in these. The management should have a copy of the collective bargaining agreement - again, talk to the union if they're not helpful.
3. Hopefully your employer can, otherwise he/she isn't a very good employer! If you have more specific questions about taxes, you can always contact the Swedish Tax Authority, and regarding other fees (such as payments to pension funds), you can contact the union.

Good luck and welcome to Sweden!

Comment: Thank you for the response. I had the discussion with management, I cannot say that they are bad - but they cannot provide such information. Clearly. They said like we will clarify your questions - but no response yet. So I sarted to investigate this by myself - when I will finish to collect the information from agencies you have specified - I will post the process here.